# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 68

Tags: java, sockets, objectinputstream

I have a client and server that have a ObjectInputStream in and out.  When I use it for the client to send data it does.  But when I try to the same object type back it gives me the above error.

Server:
ClientWorker:

```
public void run(){
      String line = null;
      try{
          oout = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());  
          oin = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream()); 
          in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
          out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
      } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println("in or out failed");
          Mud.conn[connnmb]=0;
          Mud.sock[connnmb]=null;
      }
```

Command to trigger the send:

```
    else if (line.startsWith("stats")){
        Debug.disPlr(plr);
        Mud.sock[conn].oout.writeObject(plr);
    }
```

Section to receive the object:

```
                      newguy=in.readLine();
                  if (newguy.equals("¥done")){
                      plr=(Player)oin.readObject();
                      System.out.println(">"+plr.getPassword());
                      out.println("¥ok");
```

Client:
Socket connection:

```
           try{
         socket = new Socket("localhost", 42024);
         oout = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());  
         oin = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
         out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), 
                     true);
         in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
         connected=1;
         //Thread obsock=new Thread(new objectSocket());
         //obsock.start();
       } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
           Styles.writeConsole("Unknown host");
       } catch  (IOException e) {
           Styles.writeConsole("No I/O");
       }
```

Send the object:

```
}else if (line.equals("¥plr")){
    out.println("¥done");
    oout.writeObject(plr);
```

Receive plr object:

```
    if (e.getSource()==btnchar){
    out.println("stats");
    try {
        Object read=oin.readObject();
        plr=(Player)read;

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        System.out.println("shit");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    cd=new ClassDisplay();
```

Player object being sent:

```
package net.bearfather.Mud;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Player implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int conn=0;
    private Mob mob=null;
    private Boolean combat=false;
    private Boolean blessed=false;
    private Spell[] activesp=new Spell[10];
    private int combattype=0;
    private int combatspell=0;
    private int rec=0;
    private String name="blank";
    private String password="blank";
    private int clss=0;
    private String race="none";
    private ArrayList<String> inv=new ArrayList<String>();
    private int lvl;
    private int exp=0;
    private int cash=0;
    private int lastbaught=0;
    private ArrayList<String> abils=new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> tabils=new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> eabils=new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> rtn=new ArrayList<String>();
    private int room=1;
    private int map=1;
    private int mana=0;
    private int curmana=0;
    private int manargn=0;
    //hitpoints
    private int maxHps=10;
    private int curmaxHps=10;
    private int curHps=10;
    //defenses and attacks
    private int ac=0;
    private int cac=0;
    private int dr=0;
    private int cdr=0;
    private int mr=0;
    private int cmr=0;
    private int att=0;
    private int catt=0;
    private int sc=0;
    private int csc=0;
    private int minhit=0;
    private int cminhit=0;
    private int maxhit=3;
    private int cmaxhit=0;
    //stats
    private int str=0;
    private int dex=0;
    private int con=0;
    private int wis=0;
    private int itl=0;
    private int chr=0;
```

}

Now I know I'm new to the object sockets so I'm sure I'm missing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same type for input/output streams in both ends (server, client). So, change your code to:

```
oout = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());  
oin = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream()); 
// REMOVE THIS LINE in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
// REMOVE THIS LINE out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
```

Remove the other in & out

and

```
oout = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());  
oin = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
// REMOVE THIS LINE out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
// REMOVE THIS LINE in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

Remove the other in & out

Comment: But I have been using the in and out on both for normal strings.  Should I use just the one for strings too?  Like I said I'm very new.

Comment: You cannot "overuse" it. There are only two streams per socket. One that goes in and the other goes out. You utilize one type to deal with them (e.g. DataInputStream/DataOutputStream, ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream, ...etc). For your case, you can use ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream even for String objects

Comment: Thank you! That was my issue.  I now have learned a little more about sockets, I would upvote you but I have no rank:(

Comment: @BearFather The issue isn't with sockets, it is with using two kinds of streams, at least one of which is buffered. Data intended for one stream can end up in the other one.